# Create method with join table - has and belongs to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

Ok, so I have a problem. I try to add some ingredient_ids to my database, but I can't figure it out how i can do it.

In my controller i have method create

```
def create
  @drink = Drink.new(drink_params)
  @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
  if @drink.save
    @drink.ingredients << @ingredient
    redirect_to drinks_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And then I have error: Couldn't find ingredient without an ID.

And but when I change @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id]) to @ingredient = Ingredient.all everything works fine. But I don't want to add all my ingredients to drink, just some of them.

Can anyone help me with this and explain it step by step? I will be grateful.

Comment: You're looking for accepts_nested_attributes_for: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

To save ingredients along with drinks you need to add [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to your `Drink` model:

```
# app/models/drink.rb

class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  ...
end
```

Then add `ingredients_attributes` as permitted param attributes in `drink_params` method of your controller. The set of fields for ingredients depend on your realization. For example, if you want to have UI where user can type an ingredient name and the new record for that ingredient to be created only if there is no such ingredient in the db yet, then you need to look up into `ingrediends` table and add `id` to `ingredients_attributes`:

```
# app/controllers/drinks_controller.rb

class DrinksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @drink = Drink.new(drink_params)
    if @drink.save
      redirect_to drinks_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def drink_params
    params.require(:drink).permit(:name, ingredients_attributes: [:name]).tap do |p|
      p[:ingredients_attributes].each do |i|
        ingredient = Ingredient.find_by(name: i[:name])
        i[:id] = ingredient.id if ingredient
      end
    end
  end
end
```